# traversing an unknown xml doc via xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to traverse through some xml document, whose structure is not known to me. Is it possible to get all the node(Document, Element, Text)'s name and values by using xpath?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to select all the nodes in the document, or a tuple of document URI, element QName and string value for each element in the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

XPath alone can get the data but it's not very good at returning composite results. The following XQuery gives you a starter:

```
//*/<element name="{name()}" parent="{name(..)}" value="{if (*) then '(composite)' else string(.)}"/>
```

For more detail, you'll need to specify your required output more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably want**:

```
//node() | //@* | //namespace::*
```

**This selects the union of all nodes** (the document node (`/`), elements, text nodes, comment nodes and processing-instruction nodes), **all attribute nodes and all namespace nodes**.

The XPath engine used usually provides the result of evaluating such an expression as some kind of container where the representations of the selected nodes are in document order, and one can iterate over the members of that container.